# Webcam not working in 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, skype, webcam, cheese

I am using a pretty old laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04
The only problem that I had is the Webcam that is detected in Skype/Cheese as "Webcam SCD1100" but just can show a black screen.

I've found this article and followed the steps, but without success:
https://forum.ubuntu-it.org/viewtopic.php?t=511079

```
$ uname -a <br/>
Linux alvenan-PC 5.7.6-050706-generic #202006241631 SMP Wed Jun 24 16:43:29 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
WebCam SCB-1100N: WebCam SCB-11 (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl -D
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : WebCam SCB-1100N: WebCam SCB-11
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4
    Driver version   : 5.7.6
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
```

```
$ dmesg | grep WebCam
[    1.463435] usb 1-1.4: Product: WebCam SCB-1100N
[    4.069263] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device WebCam SCB-1100N (2232:1008)
[    4.141194] input: WebCam SCB-1100N: WebCam SCB-11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input13
```

```
$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.200146] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.200146] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.200146] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.412174] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.07
[    0.412177] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.412179] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.412181] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.7.6-050706-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.412183] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.432135] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.07
[    0.432136] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.432137] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.432138] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.7.6-050706-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.432139] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.752005] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    0.772018] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    0.908736] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.908738] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    0.928735] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    0.928737] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.196032] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.216013] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.330519] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0745, bcdDevice= 6.56
[    1.330526] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.330529] usb 2-1.2: Product: Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
[    1.330532] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    1.349541] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.349543] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.352368] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:045E:0745.0001/input/input6
[    1.408014] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    1.412310] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[    1.414734] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/0003:045E:0745.0002/input/input7
[    1.414932] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/0003:045E:0745.0002/input/input8
[    1.463432] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=2232, idProduct=1008, bcdDevice= 0.19
[    1.463434] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.463435] usb 1-1.4: Product: WebCam SCB-1100N
[    1.463436] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: 123
[    1.472252] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1
[    1.472696] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/0003:045E:0745.0003/input/input9
[    1.518390] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3004, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    1.518397] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.518400] usb 2-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    1.518404] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[    1.518407] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
[    1.532232] input: Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.2/0003:045E:0745.0003/input/input11
[    1.532469] hid-generic 0003:045E:0745.0003: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input2
[    4.042668] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.053578] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    4.141194] input: WebCam SCB-1100N: WebCam SCB-11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input13
[    4.141296] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    6.105346] audit: type=1400 audit(1593316493.163:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=575 comm="apparmor_parser"
```